# AWS Glue Crawler fails with 11 million files on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Got 11 million+ json files in S3.

Tried to crawl and catalog them to AWS Glue.

**JSON File Details:**

Each file size is from 250KB to 2MB uncompressed.

**Logs:**

```
BENCHMARK : Running Start Crawl for Crawler impall
ERROR : Internal Service Exception
BENCHMARK : Crawler has finished running and is in state READY
```

Am I missing any step in processing those huge files?

Comment: This might be related to the code you're using, for example if you're keeping every file you read in memory. Could you post the relevant pieces of code here?

Comment: There is no code related to crawling, as its responsibility is to crawl an S3 bucket or s3 bucket path and populate the metadata to AWS Glue. What code are you asking here?

Comment: Contacted AWS Glue support, they don't know how to resolve the scalability issue, issue is AWS Glue cannot handle huge list of files from S3.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I'll try using Kinesis Firehose to group the JSON files before sending them to S3, but at some point in time I think I will hit the limit again (I do not know for sure what the limit is in terms of file count btw).

Comment: Hey guys, how did you handle this generic error?

Comment: Interesting question: I also want to know the limit of AWS Glue Crawler, in terms of files count and/or file sizes.

Comment: @DaniloGomes Its bit late but one way I solved this is by creating the partition in the AWS Glue table using boto3. This cannot be done on first run and also make sure the files is the folder are of same schema so that when we query from Athena it will be able to read these files

Answer (score 0):

S3 + Glue Crawler is known for poor performance when having a lot of small files.

What you could do is to create a [Amazon Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/basic-create.html) to append your JSON files so that you have less files but each file is bigger in size. This will allow your glue crawler to be able to finish.

the following architecture can help:

```
S3 > Lambda > Firehose > S3 > Glue Crawler
```

- Put an s3 event that triggers a lambda on your s3 bucket that contains all the JSON files.
- When the lambda is triggered, read the json file and send it to the endpoint of the Firehose you created.
- The Firehose is configured to wait for x seconds and to wait until the concatenated file reaches a size threshold before dumping the result back to S3. Consider dumping the result to a columnar format like parquet, if you are working with tabular data
- Once all json files are passed through Firehose, you can trigger your Glue Crawler.